# TypeScript: How to access onChange event data without error? (Object is possibly 'null')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, preact

Please see this minimum example below:

```
/** @jsx h */
import { h, FunctionalComponent } from 'preact';

const Test: FunctionalComponent = () => {
  return (
    <select
      value="1"
      onChange={(event) => {
        console.log(event.target.value);
      }}
    >
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
  );
};
```

[image: image showing unsafe access to object field]

How do I resolve the error where it says `Object is possibly 'null'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a "TypeScript safety check" to inform you that `event.target` may be null, which would cause access to `event.target.value` to throw an error at run-time.

This warning/error can be silenced by using the ["non-null assertion operation"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator):

```
<select value="1" onChange={(event) => {
    /* Add ! after target to state that "event.target!" is defined and 
       that value field can be safely accessed. This is a non-null 
       assertion */
    console.log(event.target!.value);
}}>
```

Or by checking that `event.target` is defined before accessing it:

```
<select value="1" onChange={(event) => {

    const { target } = event;
    if(target) {
        /* The ! is not needed seeing target is dedeuced as being defined */
        console.log(target.value);
    }
}}>
```

Comment: Neither of these solutions work for me. typescript 3.5.3
The non-null assertion operator has no affect and even if my condition explicitly says `target !== null`, I still get the "object is possibly 'null'" error.

Comment: @Vince that's strange - can you please provide a snippet of the code that's causing the problem (ie via a git gist)?

Comment: @Vince please verify the type of event you are defining in your event handler. if it is not `React.ChangeEvent` then you might still get error unless you check for event.target && event.target.value before using.

Comment: You can try using the check: `if (event.target.files)`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check `event.target.value` before accessing it. See below

```
    <select value="1" onChange={(event) => {
    event.target.value? console.log(event.target.value):null;
}}
```

I had a similar issue when selecting file

```
<input
  type="file"
  onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    formik.setFieldValue(
      "file",
      (event?.target.files && event?.target?.files[0]) ?? ""
    );
    formik.setFieldValue(
      "fileName",
      (event?.target.files && event?.target?.files[0].name) ?? ""
    );
  }}
/>;
```